# Need help with problem related to latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

My husband's boss is taking all the sales team to a team building event in Denver, Colorado and he has been sending hints for the last week. Now he has sent a math problem and told us it has something to do with Latitude and longitude. I have worked on this problem for days. If you could help that would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Here is the problem:
$$\begin{align}13&+(-459.67)+(45-45-90)+14.0067(2)\\ &+1,000(2)+10^9+(-459.67)\\ &+(100^2 \times 2)+((101)^2)^2\end{align}$$

The bossman said it doesn't necessarily have to do with just the answer. Please someone put me out of my misery! ha!

Comment: I'm sorry I guess the math problem can be broke down into latitude and longitude coordinates and I was just wondering if anyone else is able to figure out how.

Comment: Is the "$2\times 2$" supposed to be in parentheses, perhaps?

Comment: I guess that the boss said to dissect the problem and it should be apparent what it is about but I have dissected this problem like crazy.

Comment: the (100 to the second power X2)

Comment: Also, what does "it doesn't necessarily have to do with just the answer" mean? What is the "it", here? Also, the answer to what? The "problem" is just an expression--nothing has been asked, so far as I can tell. Do the hints he's been sending have anything to do with the problem, perhaps? If you post those, too, it might be easier for someone to see how to break it down.

Comment: Im sorry after the (459.60)+(100to the second powerx2)+((101)second power)second power

Comment: It looks like it's just a matter of calculating a number. The issue is that there doesn't seem to be a "problem" here to solve really, just a calculation to carry out. I would assume that 1000(2) is $1000^2$, but then you use ^ in other places so I don't know if that's right. Also your $10^9$ and $101^4$ terms will completely drown out everything else, and I don't know of anything in geography where you'd deal with numbers that large. Lots of redundant brackets. The whole thing just looks weird. Some legs may be being pulled here.

Comment: the hints don't really have anything to do with the problem. And really I had no idea if it was a problem or an expression. I was just seeing if anyone had a idea if this could become an latitude and longitude coordinate.

Comment: I was using the ^ for like 10 to the ninth power.

Comment: @Stephanie I have turned the arithmetic expression into a more readable latex form.  Please check that I have translated it correctly.

Comment: @Neal yes thanks a million I didn't have the fancy way to write it correctly. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Neal: I was a bit reticent to do that, myself, and only because of the "45-45-90" bit. I didn't think it likely that a description of a similarity class of triangles would be relevant, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Now I am really confused!

Comment: The other clues to the activity were riddles. I would be happy to email them to you if you are bored! lol

Comment: @Cameron Your suggestion and the team-building nature of the question raises the possibility that it's not a math problem at all, but rather something like "on the 13-th of this month (and) [something involving -459.67] (and) [a right triangle]...". There's nothing obviously related to the latitude and longitude of Denver. My guess is that without knowing a lot more about the company there's no way of getting any solution.

Comment: @Rick you could be right. I have no idea the other clues were written words in a rhythm like riddle form.

Comment: It has something to do with Triangle, Nitrogen and Absolute zero. And the boss said 13 is something math people should know. Sorry just thought I would follow up in case anyone is still checking.

Comment: Aha! So I was right about the triangle (pun intended). See my answer for some (potential) hints.

Comment: It would be nice to see the rest of the hints to get a better feeling for the way the poser thinks.

Comment: “I married a wonderful woman…that was born from a crazy dressed German, who stands as tall as a tree.
He wears a Tyrolean hat…that looks like it is made from a dead bat…a Flying Fox is what I see.
His skills are one of a kind…teaching sermons and cooking combined…even did a stint in the military.
He learned to point and fire…he learned to fly on a wire…understanding that the wind could always be too gusty.
He used to be my boss…they called him Chef Guggenmoss…boy he scared the shit out of me.
One day I got him mad.showing him what skills I really had.and beating the life out of he.

Comment: Now is another chance…when I win, you will see me dance…and boy do I glide so gracefully.”

Comment: “Our destination of choice is frequented by many.  Watching a woodpecker off of route 20, you may also see some kudzu, as there is plenty.  Or perhaps you like the romantic destination near 476, where sitting in a champagne glass and shooting uzi’s may come into the mix.  Either way, the visit always seems to fly by at 200 mph…long time remembering where you were the king of the tower.”

Comment: @RossMillikan here is the other riddles the poser sent! hahaha! Thanks for the chuckle!

Comment: @Stephanie:  Sounds very much like Jayson Wechter's work.  We do the San Francisco Chinese treasure hunt many years.  http://sftreasurehunts.com/hunts/chinese_new_year/  It helps a lot to have a local-they will recognize many of the items.

Comment: Boss just said an alternate formula for the last two is 5^2X2

Comment: five to the second power times two

Comment: one hour left and we have to make our guess!!! ahhhh!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Based on your edit, the expression, itself, evaluates to: $$1,104,081,432.6734$$

Your comment hints give me a few ideas:

(i) $13$ is a prime number. Perhaps a reference to the prime meridian as a starting point?

(ii) $-459.67$ is an approximation to absolute zero ($0$ Kelvins) in degrees Fahrenheit.

(iii) $45$-$45$-$90$ is how one often indicates the angles of a right isosceles triangle.

(iv) $14.0067$ is the atomic mass of Nitrogen. Pure Nitrogen is found in nature as a molecule $N_2$ (two nitrogen atoms bonded together). This may be connected to the $(2)$ appended to the end of the $14.0067$.

I'm not sure what to think about the rest of it. Hopefully this gives you some clues....

Comment: I like your idea of taking the "calculation" apart.  I might replace the -459.67 with OK or OR (0 Kelvin or Rankine).  The powers of 10 might become K or M for 1000, B for 10^9.  Nothing comes to this math person's mind about 13 except prime or maybe king (rank in deck of cards).

Comment: Using the hint that this has to do with latitude and longitude, we might parse this as follows:
13 -> prime (meridian)

Comment: Oops! Spent more than five minutes writing my comment. Here's the rest.
Using the hint that this has to do with latitude and longitude, we might parse this as follows:
13 -> prime (meridian)
(45-45-90) -> north and west coordinates
-459.67 -> zero degrees
Then the last term, $((101)^2)^2$ could be interpreted as $101^4=104060401$, which is a scaled version of 104, fairly close to the west longitude of Denver. Because of the two zero degree terms, it's reasonable to expect that it somehow gives the N and W coordinates of some location, but it's not clear right now.

Comment: Here is the posers other hints. LOL

Comment: Where are the other hints?

Comment: Cameron I put them in the comments section. Sorry!

Comment: Wow.... That's just silly.

Comment: boss just said the alternate formula for the last two is five the second power times 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly based on @Cameron's hints, doesn't quite match the problem in it's current form, and doesn't have to do with latitude or longitude. But:

- 13 = M
- -459.67 = O
- 45-45-90 = V
- ? = I
- 14.0067 = N
- 1000 = G
- $10^9$ = T
- -459.67 = O
- $100^2\times 7 + 101^2$ = 80201

Alternatively, my first thought was the triangle might be for I and there might be an interpretation of 13 as G.

I was trying to coerce a Denver zip code, but $100^2\times 2 + 101^2\times 2=40402$ or $100^2\times 6 + 101^2\times 2=80402$ work for Annville, KY and Golden, CO, too.

Comment: I don't get where the $T$ is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you just feed it to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13%2b%28-459.67%29%2b%2845-45-90%29%2b14.0067%282%29%2b1,000%282%29%2b10%5E9%2b%28459.60%29%2b%28100%5E2%20x%202%29%2b%28%28101%29%5E2%29%5E2&dataset=), 1.1040823519434 × 10^9 comes back.  This is 1,104,082,351.9434 when not in scientific notation.  This assumes the (2)s are to be multipliers, not squares.  Usually latitude/longitude in the US has fifteen digits, DD MM.MMM in latitude first, followed by DDD MM.MMM in longitude (at least the geocachers use this).  This doesn't fit that pattern.  Google uses DD.DDDD DDD.DDDD, which is one digit short.  I can find 104.9434 embedded, which is a nice latitude in Denver, but can't find a reasonable latitude from what is left.

Comment: Looks like she had a typo in the original post. See if that changes anything.